# what is type of file with format like "#train.py# ",and how to delete it?

Tags: python, macos, unix, terminal

This is directory(On macOS ) in terminal, I was editing a python file named "train.py" when learning opencv,and I don't know why there is a file named "#train.py# ",I tried to delete it ,but failed.

[Directory screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihHWy.png)

Comment: It's your editor's autosave file. So you use Emacs?

Comment: Yes! I remember I have tried to use emacs to edit the original "train.py" file.It is helpful !